# C Function and Variable Scope from K&R

Tags: c

I am currently reading K&R this code is confusing me, especially when it comes to variable/function scope...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int getline(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

/*print the longest input line*/
void main()
{
    int len;
    int max;
    char line[MAXLINE];
    char longest[MAXLINE];

    max = 0;
    while((len = getline(line, MAXLINE))> 0)
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
    if (max > 0)
        printf("%s", longest);
    return 0;
}

/*getline: read a line into s, return length*/
int getline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    for (i = 0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; i++)
        s[i] = c;
    if(c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

/*copy: copy 'from' into 'to': assume to is big enough*/
void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;

}
```

How does the `getline()` function have the scope to save into the `line[]` array that is located in `main()`?

How does the `copy()` function have the scope to save into the `longest[]` array that is located in `main()`?

I can understand if the functions were nested inside of `main()`, but in this example they are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are passing a pointer to the first element of your arrays (declared in `main`) to your function. For more clarity prototypes could also be written as

```
int getline(char *line, int maxline);
void copy(char *to, char *from);
```

When you call your function from `main` and pass array name as its argument then the array name converted to the pointer to its first element. So, what copied to the function parameter is the starting address of array, not the array itself. Now any changes to the passed address (i.e, array) is also reflected to `main`.

Comment: Does this only hold true for arrays?

Comment: Yes. You can't pass entire array to a function.

Answer (score 1):

In C, if a function calls another function, passing the address of any of its variables to the called function, the called function may access and manipulate the data at that address any possible way it wants.
Here, the address of `char line[]` is passed to the function `getline()` which enables `getline` to access and modify and fill `line[]`.

If you're studying arrays and functions, you most definitely have used `scanf()` in the previous lessons. Ever wondered how `scanf()` can fill data into a variable defined inside `main()`? :-)
After all, `scanf()` is a yet another function right?
And now you may surely be able to explain why we add an `&` (address of operator) before an `int` or `char` variable when calling `scanf()`. 
We are just passing the function the address of the location where data is to be filled.

Answer (score 0):

> How does the getline() function have the scope to save into the line[] array that is located in main()?

`getline()` gets the copied value of the address of `line` in the local variable `char s[]`

> How does the copy() function have the scope to save into the longest[] array that is located in main()?

Because you are passing the address of the variable.

`copy(longest, line);` becomes `copy(to, from)` - so to say. The values of the base addresses are copied.

This has more to do with pointers and passing arguments than scope. You are confusing these concepts.

Answer (score 0):

The `getline()` function doesn't "have the scope" to store directly to `line`, but that doesn't matter since the address of `line` is passed to `getline` and becomes the address of the local `s` argument.

This means that while `getline()` is indeed writing to exactly the same memory as is used by `line` in `main()`, it's not aware of that. You'll notice that `line` is not mentioned by name inside `getline()`.

Comment: Though your answer is correct, I would disagree with your first line. `getline()` does save directly to `line[]` though without have the knowledge that where it is writing data is actually `line[]`.
Just like here in India, the grand parents never know your real name and always interact with you by your nickname, but that doesn't mean that they're not talking to `realName(unwind)`.
:-)

Comment: @reza.safiyat I rewrote it, perhaps it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

line is declared in main, and its storage is in the main only. inside your other functions i.e. copy and getline, the base address of the array is passed, like a pointer. Hence, copy and getline are able to use the address and access the array's which are define in your main.